# How to diagnose a vnc-crashing problem?

Tags: xfce, remote-desktop, vnc, remote-x-session, tightvncserver

Tightvnc server keeps crashing on my dedicated Ubuntu server. The Ubuntu Unity main desktop is unaffected, but the tightvnc server crashes and takes down any program that was running in its (xfce) remote session. Crashes usually occur whenever more than 1 program is launched in the remote session, or if Chrome by itself (no tabs) is launched.

Is there any other/better way to diagnose this problem other than reading the logs in /home/user/.vnc? I've tried reading the logs, but they do not add any new log data during or after a crash, so I don't think it's telling me anything about the reason for the crash. Here is the log file from right after a crash: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13298254/. Is there any other place to look to diagnose the reason behind all these crashes?